# Call timeout() & input() inside a shared groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Groovy class shared between different Jenkins pipelines. I would like to move this part of the pipeline inside the shared groovy script

```
timeout (time: 15, unit: 'SECONDS') {
    input ('Validation is required')
}
```

But it doesnt recognize input () or timeout()
so I have to pass them as parameters

```
def requireValidation (Closure timeout, Closure input) {
    timeout (time: 15, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        input ('Validation is required')
    }
}
```

In there a way to import input & timeout inside the groovy script in a way I can have function without parameters?

```
 def requireValidation()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how use call `requireValidation`?

Comment: inside the jenkins pipeline requireValidation(this.&timeout, this.&input)

Answer (score 0):

A normal groovy class `G.groovy`:

```
class G {
    def hello(s) {
        println("hello ${s}")
    }
    def timeout( ...
    def input( ...
}
```

and the script that needs to use it main.groovy:

```
def requireValidation(){
    def script = new GroovyScriptEngine('.').with {
        loadScriptByName('G.groovy')
    }
    this.metaClass.mixin script

    hello('jon');
}


requireValidation()
```

which will print:

> hello jon

The import is occurring inside the `requireValidation` function (inspired by Python) using the `GroovyScriptEngine`. The direct usage of the function is due to the magic of `this.metaClass.mixin script`. A better approach in `main.groovy` would be:

```
def script = new GroovyScriptEngine('.').with {
    loadScriptByName('G.groovy')
}
this.metaClass.mixin script

def requireValidation(){
    hello('jon');
}

requireValidation()
```

Comment: yes thank you, but my question is related to    ` def timeout( ...
    def input( ... ` which are Jenkins function that I need to pass as parameter `requireValidation(this.&timeout, this.&input)` and instead I'd like to have them for example as Mvn dependency or something like this

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling I was missing something. So that means there is no class that you can import using `loadScriptByName`, I didn't know `timeout` and `input` were jenkins functions.